# Why not installed podfile?

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I created my app. When I try to install a podfile there, it shows me an error:

```
――― MARKDOWN TEMPLATE ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

### Command
/usr/local/bin/pod init

### Report
* What did you do?
* What did you expect to happen?
* What happened instead?

### Stack
   CocoaPods : 1.5.3
        Ruby : ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]
    RubyGems : 2.5.2.3
        Host :  (18G95)
       Xcode : 11.0 (11A420a)
         Git : git version 2.21.0 (Apple Git-122)
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib
Repositories : master - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ 6359a249f00fcdd63324ef44a867f16591aac646

### Plugins

cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.2
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.0
cocoapods-stats       : 1.0.0
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.3.0
cocoapods-try         : 1.1.0

### Error

RuntimeError - [!] Xcodeproj doesn't know about the following attributes {"inputFileListPaths"=>[], "outputFileListPaths"=>[]} for the 'PBXShellScriptBuildPhase' isa.
If this attribute was generated by Xcode please file an issue: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj/issues/new
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.7/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:321:in `configure_with_plist'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.7/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:262:in `new_from_plist'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.7/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:350:in `object_with_uuid'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.7/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:300:in `block (2 levels) in configure_with_plist'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.7/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:299:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.7/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:299:in `block in configure_with_plist'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.7/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:296:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.7/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:296:in `configure_with_plist'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.7/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:262:in `new_from_plist'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.7/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:350:in `object_with_uuid'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.7/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:300:in `block (2 levels) in configure_with_plist'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.7/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:299:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.7/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:299:in `block in configure_with_plist'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.7/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:296:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.7/lib/xcodeproj/project/object.rb:296:in `configure_with_plist'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.7/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:262:in `new_from_plist'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.7/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:203:in `initialize_from_file'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/xcodeproj-1.5.7/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:103:in `open'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/command/init.rb:41:in `validate!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:333:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `<main>'

――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=%5B%21%5D+Xcodeproj+doesn%27t+know+about+the+following+attributes+%7B%22inputFileListPaths%22%3D%3E%5B%5D%2C+%22outputFileListPaths%22%3D%3E%5B%5D%7D+for+the+%27PBXShellScriptBuildPhase%27+isa.%0AIf+this+attribute+was+generated+by+Xcode+please+file+an+issue%3A+https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FCocoaPods%2FXcodeproj%2Fissues%2Fnew&type=Issues

If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/gh_inspector-1.1.3/lib/gh_inspector/sidekick.rb:95:in `parse_results': undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  tap
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/gh_inspector-1.1.3/lib/gh_inspector/sidekick.rb:34:in `search'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/gh_inspector-1.1.3/lib/gh_inspector/inspector.rb:68:in `search_query'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/gh_inspector-1.1.3/lib/gh_inspector/inspector.rb:62:in `search_exception'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:119:in `search_for_exceptions'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:67:in `report_error'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:396:in `handle_exception'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:337:in `rescue in run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:324:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/cocoapods-1.5.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/pod:22:in `<main>'
```

Please help me for fix this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because of this line:

> Xcodeproj doesn't know about the following attributes {"inputFileListPaths"=>[], "outputFileListPaths"=>[]} for the 'PBXShellScriptBuildPhase' isa.

This is a [know bug](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7835) introduced in Xcode 10, that has conflict with Cocoapods 1.5.x. The .xcodeproj file included two vars inside the `scriptBuildPhase` that Cocoapods doesn't know how to parse.

You have two possible solutions:

1) Updating Cocoapods xcodeproj gem:

```
sudo gem update xcodeproj
```

2) Manually removing `inputFileListPaths` and `outputFileListPaths` from your project file:

Right click in the `.xcodeproj` file > `Show Package Content` > open the `.pbxproj` file using any text editor > find and remove all the `inputFileListPaths` and `outputFileListPaths` references:

[image: Block to remove unwanted vars]

Comment: Open the `Terminal` app, navigate to the project folder (ex: `cd  /Users/user_name/Desktop/project_folder` ) and run the command `sudo gem update xcodeproj`.

Comment: When I try to update, I see new error in terminal.The error text:  User is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported. Please can you tell how to fix these problem

Comment: You don't have admin permission with this user. Try running without `sudo`.

Comment: Everything was going well at first, but there was such a mistake: "gem update xcodeproj
Updating installed gems
Updating xcodeproj
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0 directory."

Comment: Yeah, you don't have permission to update the gem with this user. You need either a sudo user, or to remove manually the tags.

Comment: Everything worked for me, thank you very much. You helped me a lot

Comment: This is my first time on this site, tell me how to do this?

Comment: Click the ✓ mark on the answer, below the number of votes. This marks the answer as accepted, and other users can find if they have the same problem.